# Custom Transaction Column Field in Netsuite

Tags: mysql, sql, formula, netsuite

We have created a custom field on ITEM RECORDS (for Inventory AND Non-Inventory Parts) lets call this `[FIELD A]`

We now want to include this field on Transactions (Sales Orders/Invoices/Purchase Orders/etc.) lets call this `[FIELD B]`

I know we will need a Custom Transaction Column Field, however what is the best way to format/setup that column, so that `[FIELD B] = [FIELD A]` **by default**?

Side note; we want `[FIELD B]` to be editable, but the changes made are not saved to `[FIELD A]`

Answer (score 0):

In your Custom Transaction Column Field `[FIELD B]`, under the **Sourcing & Filtering** Tab, set the **Source List** dropdown value to `Item`, and **Source From** dropdown to `[FIELD A]`.

To set it as a default value but still be editable, make sure that the **Store Value** checkbox is ticked on `[FIELD B]`. Changing `[FIELD B]` will not affect the value of `[FIELD A].`

Comment: Thanks for the info, but when I go to change **Source From** to `[Field A]`, Field A isn't in **Source From** list? Have I missed a step when setting up `[Field A]` ?

Comment: Are the two fields the same Type?